# Discord.py now working on Heroku deployment

Tags: github, heroku, discord, discord.py, github-desktop

Im trying to deploy my python code on Heroku using GitHub Desktop,
i also have have .json on the files btw

[requirements]
discord.py

[Procfile]
worker : python economia.py

**HEROKU ERROR:**

```
-----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
       More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
 !     Push failed
```

**updated with new files:**
[githbu files] (https://github.com/richcipriano/billionaireboysclub)

***UPDATED HEROKU LOG:***

```
2020-08-30T20:51:18.764302+00:00 app[api]: Release v13 created by user mallkz@hotmail.com
2020-08-30T20:51:27.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-08-30T20:53:55.070715+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=billionaireboysclub.herokuapp.com request_id=d0cb7997-13a0-4e27-945e-6f04d471f5e7 fwd="107.184.213.12" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-08-30T20:53:55.776349+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=billionaireboysclub.herokuapp.com request_id=64a55a40-5c9e-4c9e-b351-9120b8d87e1a fwd="107.184.213.12" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-08-30T20:59:14.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user mallkz@hotmail.com
2020-08-30T20:59:46.151834+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 52d5b11d by user mallkz@hotmail.com
2020-08-30T20:59:46.151834+00:00 app[api]: Release v14 created by user mallkz@hotmail.com
2020-08-30T20:59:54.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-08-30T21:05:42.259926+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=billionaireboysclub.herokuapp.com request_id=63abbf21-aa34-433c-b9e6-8a708810e334 fwd="107.184.213.12" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-08-30T21:05:43.029607+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=billionaireboysclub.herokuapp.com request_id=91edc538-2ef0-4f8e-88e3-5bb91007e6c6 fwd="107.184.213.12" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Try putting `git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py` instead of `discord.py`

Comment: Just put discord instead of discord.py and also add json to your requirements if u have imported the json library.

Comment: Idk if this has anything to do with the problme but what python version are you using? To choose the python version make a `runtime.txt` and put in `python-3.8.3` or the version you want. And If you repo is public could we have the link to it?

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the tips, successfully deployed but now I have this error now ( I updated the question with the Heroku log ) and my GitHub files ( https://github.com/richcipriano/billionaireboysclub )